# Unwanted Rounding in Division

Tags: c++, math

I have a 20-numbers long array; I want to find the arithmetic mean of all negative numbers in the array and then deduct this number from every single element of this array.
The problem is when I try to divide the sum of the values of the negative numbers by the number of negative numbers (to find the mean) it automatically gets rounded down to the nearest integer

Here's the code:

```
int main()
{
    double a1 = 0.0;
    double b2 = 0.0; // arth mean
    int arr[20] = {12, -30, 23, -43, 51, 26, 0, 88, 19, -10, 11, 2, 23, -14, 15, 6, -7, 1, -19, 120};
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        if(arr[i] < 0) {
            a1 += arr[i]; // sum of negative numbers
        }
    }
    b2 = a1 / 6;
    cout << b2;
     for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[i] - b2;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself: What is the type of the elements in `arr`?  Dose that support a decimal point?

Comment: `b2` is not rounded (apart from natural floating point numbers inaccuracy). You will only get rounding when calculating new values in `arr`

Comment: @opage_potato Are you saying `cout << b2` writes `20` to the console? Seems like it should give you something like `-20.5`

Comment: The values in the array aren't rounded, they are *truncated*.

Comment: Hi. This question is unclear because you are showing one thing that should produce a decimal (`cout <<b2`) and something that shouldn't (`cout << [arr[i]`). Which is it?  Part of a minimal, reproducible example is the "minimal" part. You should remove code that doesn't directly demonstrate the problem.

Comment: By the way, why are you assuming there are 6 negative numbers instead of counting them while you're going through the loop?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `double b2 = 0.0; // arith mean` should be `double arith_mean = 0.0;`. Use meaningful names.

Comment: in simple terms your question is "why does my output not meet my expectations?". We need to see both. Please include output and expected output in your question

Answer (score 1):

You are making changes in `arr` which is an array of type `int` so every floating data type will automatically change to ignore decimal points and the remaining number is `int` i.e `int 5 = 5.9;` will be equal to `5` which is the answer of your last line. Thus convert your array `arr` to float or double data type.

```
 float arr[20] = {12, -30, 23, -43, 51, 26, 0, 88, 19, -10, 11, 2, 23, -14, 15, 6, -7, 1, -19, 120};
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        if(arr[i] < 0) {
            a1 += arr[i]; // sum of negative numbers
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is wrong. In C++, dividing a double by an int gives a double. Try it if you don't believe me.

Comment: Your right I misread it. Deleting my posts. I thought a1 was int.

Comment: If I divide double by int, we get double but if we store that double in an integer data type, it automatically drops decimal part(this is what happens here in this question).

Answer (score -1):

I just ran the code locally and it does spit out -20.5. The full output is this:

```
-20.532 -9 43 -22 71 46 20 108 39 10 31 22 43 6 35 26 13 21 1 140
```

Perhaps your confusion is that you are not adding whitespace after the first number? Try

```
cout << b2 << " ";
```

Instead and maybe it will be more clear. Note also that when doing this:

```
arr[i] = arr[i] - b2;
```

The RHS is a float and gets truncated when stored in `arr[i]`. To avoid this, make `arr` an array of floats rather than ints.

Comment: @UpAndAdam But a1 is a double. Run the code if you don't believe me.